# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when connecting to remote node

Tags: web3js

I'm getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when connecting to my remote geth node with

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://"+RPCIP+":"+RPCPort));
```

and  `web3.min.js` which is included via:

```
<script src="./source/js/web3.min.js"></script>
```

the node is running with:

```
./root/go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --light --cache 4096 --rpc --rpcaddr "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" --rpcport XXXX --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3,net"
```

it works when working with node.js but doesn't with the js file. How can I fix that?

Comment: Could you post the code related to this failure. Do you have any other details you get along with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ?

Comment: web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://"+RPCIP+":"+RPCPort));